# Speed up replace all

Tags: functions, function-construction

I have large list of rules, I would like to use `list/.rule`, but assume that rule is a set of rules `rule 1, rule2 rule...`I want the Replace All to find first match of rule 1 then apply rule,and so go over to look for match of rule two. This would speed up the process in a very large dataset.

I want the first rule on only the first match found, then continue with the next rule from start of the list, if there are any cases of no match go to to next rule. Result would be the list but with applied rules where matches of patterns have been found.If a rule changes a value, and that new value is matched by a later rule, then leave it untouched.(Do not apply rule on al ready changed value)

Example:

```
list={{"02jan2001", "A", 47.98, ""}, {"03jan2001", "A", 52.9312,   
 ""}, {"04jan2001", "A", 54.9353, ""}, {"05jan2001", "A", 51.9292,   
 ""}, {"08jan2001", "A", 50.2198, ""}, {"09jan2001", "A", 49.9841,   
 ""}}

Rules= {{"02jan2001", "A", q$___} -> 0.815473`, {"03jan2001", "A", q$___} -> 
 0.840296`, {"04jan2001", "A", q$___} -> 0.833659`}
```

Wanted output   `{0.815473, 0.840296, 0.833659, {"05jan2001", "A", 51.9292, 
  ""}, {"08jan2001", "A", 50.2198, ""}, {"09jan2001", "A", 49.9841, 
  ""}}`

Comment: Your question is ambiguous. Do you mean you want a replacement by the first rule on only the first match found, then continue with the next rule *from that point* in the target, etc? What if the is no match? Please provide a minimal example of input and output...

Comment: Could you try `list/.rule1/.rule2` etc.?

Comment: Without more detail all I'd suggest is that you read the docs on `ReplaceRepeated` and `ReplaceList`. Also for speeding up replacements generally see `Dispatch` and note that if you know the structure of your list then try replacing to a specific levelspec rather than all levels.

Comment: I have added explanation to the question, hopefully it is not ambiguous anymore.

Comment: @ALEXANDER: With your expanded explanation, what if a rule changes a value, and that *new* value is matched by a later rule? Does it get changed again, or is it to be left untouched?

Comment: To be left untouched

Comment: @ALEXANDER My interpretation is that `myReplaceAll[{1, 2, 3}, {_Integer -> 4, _Integer -> 5, _Integer -> 6}]` should return `{4, 5, 6}`.  Is this correct?

Comment: So far, none of the answers (including mine) get it right (as far as handling any kind of rule one might use in `ReplaceAll` without the "first found" restriction). Could you expand on the "speed up the process in a very large dataset" part of your OP? What exactly do you think can be (or you want) sped up? I'm beginning to think that the overhead involved in having the "first found" constraint will wildly explode timings vs vanilla `ReplaceAll`. Also, are your rules simple replacements, or are conditionals/references to the patterns/etc. involved?

Comment: Perhaps a concrete example of the "dataset" and typical rules you expect with desired result could be added to OP: all the machinations in our various answers re: handling heads of expressions, etc. are for naught if you're just wanting simple numeric/symbolic substitution rules with the "first found" restriction...

Comment: That is correct Mr.Wizard

Comment: @ALEXANDER The example you appended doesn't require the behavior that I indicated in a comment above; it doesn't require avoiding replacement of already-modified expressions.  Is this behavior important or not?  Further, your rules appear (in `Rules`) in the same order as they are matched within your `list`; is this always the case?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I would like that it avoids replacement of already-modified expressions. It would make it more applicable for other situations, and it would be random not sorted as in this case. Also I saw the comment you gave about how the function works, but using Trace, Im still not able to get what is going on.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example of a way to do this.

```
list = RandomInteger[5, 20]

(* {5, 1, 3, 2, 2, 2, 0, 4, 0, 3, 2, 4, 1, 1, 1, 5, 2, 5, 4, 3} *)

rules = {1 -> 2, 2 -> 3, 3 -> 4, 9 -> 8};

ReplacePart[list, Cases[Thread[Position[list, #, 1, 1] & /@ rules[[All, 1]] -> 
            rules[[All, 2]]], ({{a_}} -> b_) :> a -> b]]

(* {5, 2, 4, 3, 2, 2, 0, 4, 0, 3, 2, 4, 1, 1, 1, 5, 2, 5, 4, 3} *)
```

This works by finding the position of the first occurrence (if it exists) for each left-hand side of the rules, and re-writing the rules to use that position in place of the value.

Pretty snappy, if you need it faster that can be done at the cost of more convoluted code.

Update: Based on Mr.Wizard's comments, perhaps this is more in line with desired results:

```
repper[list_, rules_, depth_: 1] := 
 Module[{rg = GatherBy[rules, First], m1, rp},
  m1 = Map[Position[list, #[[1]], depth, #[[2]]] &, Tally[rules[[All, 1]]]];
  rp = Flatten@MapIndexed[# -> rg[[Sequence @@ #2]][[2]] &, m1, {2}];
  ReplacePart[list, rp]]

list = {1.25, 1, 2, 3, 5.5, 20, 30};

rules = {_Integer -> 4, _Integer -> 5, _Integer -> 6, _Real -> 2.5, _Integer -> 66,
         3 -> 999};

repper[list, rules]

(* {2.5, 4, 5, 6, 5.5, 66, 30} *)

repper[foo[1, {2, 3, 0, 1/3}], 
       {_Integer -> 4, _Integer -> 5, _Integer -> 6, foo -> bar, _Rational -> 2.5},
       Infinity]

(* bar[4, {5, 6, 0, 2.5}] *)
```

Comment: Nice idea. +1  Now let me see if I can find another way...

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: Thanks! I think the ordering trick would be the fastest, at the cost of much more code...

Comment: Actually this doesn't do what I think the OP wants, but it's a valid interpretation of the original question so my vote stands.  Nevertheless I am guessing that `list = {1, 2, 3};
rules = {_Integer -> 4, _Integer -> 5, _Integer -> 6};` should result in `{4, 5, 6}` for output.  Does that make sense?  (This is easy enough at a single level, but seems difficult for full `/.` behavior.)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: Yes, I agree with your assessment, perhaps further clarification by OP warranted.

Comment: Would you please give a version of `repper` that operates at all levels? (Including heads.)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: Done - I think ;=) - not deeply tested.

Comment: Thanks.  I wish I could +1 again.  Now for timings. :-)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: Ah, don't have to tell you the position cost blows, this is where the ordering trick would rule, but unless OP says timings too slow, not worth the extra code...

Comment: Well the title of the question starts with "Speed up..." but in a brief test your method is vastly superior to my clumsy attempt.  I think this is an interesting problem and I personally would like to see your regular effort on it.  (Obviously I'm not feeling inspired but I'll continue thinking.)

Answer (score 2):

Following my own interpretation of the question here is one approach.  It seems quite clumsy but I can't think of a better way at the moment.  Perhaps I can refine it later.

```
myRA[expr_, rules_List] :=
 Module[{next, f, i = 1, n = Length@rules},
   next[] /; i >  n := (f = Identity);
   next[] /; i <= n := (
     Clear[f];
     (f[#] := (next[]; #2)) & @@ rules[[i++]];
     f[other_] := f /@ Operate[f, other]
    );
   next[];
   f @ expr
 ]
```

Test:

```
myRA[foo[1, {2, 3, 0}], {_Integer -> 4, _Integer -> 5, _Integer -> 6}]
```

> ```
> foo[4, {5, 6, 0}]
> ```

This relies on evaluation within the expression, and won't work on e.g. `Hold`, which means that is it *not* equivalent to `ReplaceAll`.  Nevertheless it may have value.

Comment: **Note:** compared to rasher's `repper` this is orders of magnitude slower.  Back to the drawing board.

Comment: +1 for some subtle cleverness there. Waiting on OP clarification before pursuing other ideas...

Comment: It does work with integer pattern, but I am not able to get it to work with my type of pattern, still it is something with your code that looks very interesting. I am not able to grasp what is going one, would you be able to explain?

Comment: @ALEXANDER As noted above this scales very poorly so I don't recommend using it.  However, in answer to your question it works by continually redefining a function `f` to act as the current rule, while mapping this function across all levels of the input expression.  Each time a match is found `next[]` is called which redefines `f` to behave like the next rule in the sequence.  After writing this I realized that depending on your meaning it may not be correct as it does not start over from the beginning, but rather the last point of evaluation.  I shall look at the example that you added.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another alternative in which I assume that once a rule is applied to a list you search further along the list for matches to apply the next rule ...and so on. As with other answers the ambiguity of the OPs question probably needs to be cleared up. This is a line by line systematic approach:

```
 findPositions[list_][position_, rule_] := 
 Module[{pos},
  pos = Flatten[Position[list, rule[[1]], {1}]];
  pos = Cases[pos, x_ /; x > position, {1}, 1];
  If[pos =!= {}, First@pos, position]
  ]
```

then:

```
rules[[All, 1]] = Rest@FoldList[findPositions[list], 0, rules];
Scan[(list[[#[[1]]]] = #[[2]]) &, rules]
```

For example:

```
list = {1, 2, 3};
rules = {_Integer -> 4, _Integer -> 5, _Integer -> 6};

rules[[All, 1]] = Rest@FoldList[findPositions[list], 0, rules];
Scan[(list[[#[[1]]]] = #[[2]]) &, rules]
list
(* {4, 5, 6} *)
```

and

```
rules = {1 -> 9, 2 -> 3, 3 -> 4, 9 -> 8};
list = {5, 1, 3, 2, 2, 2, 0, 4, 0, 3, 2, 4, 1, 9, 1, 5, 2, 5, 4, 3};

rules[[All, 1]] = Rest@FoldList[findPositions[list], 0, rules];
Scan[(list[[#[[1]]]] = #[[2]]) &, rules]
list
(* {5, 9, 3, 3, 2, 2, 0, 4, 0, 4, 2, 4, 1, 8, 1, 5, 2, 5, 4, 3} *)
```

Comment: +1 for addressing my interpretation, but can you make this work for all levels?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard short answer would be yes but obviously requires a re-jig of the code to accomplish that. Long answer is that I have already spent way too long on this and won't do anymore until the OP offers some clarity.

Answer (score 0):

If a replacement is only to be made once for each rule then I think you can re-think the problem and do it this way:

```
rules = {1 -> 9, 2 -> 3, 3 -> 4, 9 -> 8};
list = {5, 1, 3, 2, 2, 2, 0, 4, 0, 3, 2, 4, 1, 9, 1, 5, 2, 5, 4, 3};
Scan[(list[[Flatten@Position[list, #[[1]], {1}, 1]]] = #[[2]]) &, rules]
list

(* {5, 4, 3, 2, 2, 2, 0, 4, 0, 3, 2, 4, 1, 8, 1, 5, 2, 5, 4, 3} *)
```

As another check with `rules = {1 -> 9, 2 -> 3, 3 -> 4, 9 -> 8}` I get

```
   (* {5, 8, 4, 3, 2, 2, 0, 4, 0, 3, 2, 4, 1, 9, 1, 5, 2, 5, 4, 3} *)
```

so the second element in `list` is initially changed from 1 to 9 and then subsequently from 9 to 8. I believe that this transformation is what you are seeking.

As an aside, for applying one rule at a time to an entire list:

```
Fold[Replace[#1 , #2, {1}] &, list, rules]
```